# Ajax POST data not appearing in modal

Tags: javascript, c#, sql, ajax

I have a table that's populated by JSON data. In the last column you can open up a modal that corresponds to each row and you can add a comment in an input box---doing so will update that modal. In other words, table rows that have no comments have an empty modal and rows with at least one comment should appear in the modal that they correspond with.

In my backend manager (SQL Server Management Studio) I can see that the comments are showing up there, but they're not appearing in the modals.

I can't tell if the problem is coming from the JavaScript side (the view) or from the model, or from elsewhere.

The addition of the DocBudgetId is relatively new. Before that, the review/comment data was tied to the DocNumber and the info was appearing in the modals. I suspect that I have to make an adjustment/change to the DocBudgetId but I'm not sure how.

**Modal screenshot:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vqd4o.png The `DocNumber` appears on the top left. Comments have been made to the row that this modal belongs to but they're not appearing in the modal table.

#### Model:

```
public class ReviewRow
    {
        public Guid DocBudgetId { get; set; }
        public string DocNumber { get; set; }
        public string ReviewBy { get; set; }
        public string ReviewOn { get; set; }
        public string ReviewComment { get; set; }   
    }
```

#### View:

```
<div class="modal-body">
        <div id="review"></div>
        <table>
           <tr>
              <td>
                @Html.LabelFor(x => Model.ReviewComment)<br />
                @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.ReviewComment, new { style = "width: 200px; " })<br />
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.DocUnderReview, new { id = "txtDocUnderReview" })
                <input type="submit" value="@BB360.Models.BudgetReportingViewModel.Buttons.Review" name="@Html.NameFor(x => x.SubmitButton)" id="SubmitButton" class="btn btn-secondary" />
              </td>
           </tr>
        </table>


// --- other code --- //

function ShowReviewModal(DocBudgetId, DocNumber) { 
        $("#txtDocUnderReview").val(DocNumber);
        console.log(DocNumber)

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Doc/GetDocUnderReviewDetails",
            data: "docNumber=" + DocNumber + "&docBudgetId=" + DocBudgetId,
            timeout: 5000,
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data); // ------------- empty array
                // write out the modal table
                var tBody = $("#tblExpenseDeductionDetails tbody");
                tBody.empty();
                s = "";

                for (x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
                  let ReviewBy = data[x].ReviewBy,
                      ReviewOn = data[x].ReviewOn,
                      ReviewComment = data[x].ReviewComment;
                        s = s + "<tr>";
                        s = s + "<td>" + ReviewBy + "</td>";
                        s = s + "<td>" + ReviewOn + "</td>";
                        s = s + "<td title='" + ReviewComment.replace(/'/g, '') + "' style='max-width:550px;word-wrap: break-word;'>" + stringTruncate(ReviewComment, 65) + "</td>";
                        s = s + "</tr>";
                }

                $("#modalDocName").text(DocNumber);
                tBody[0].innerHTML = s;
                $("#ReviewModal").modal();
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });

        $("#ReviewModal").modal();
    }
```

#### Controller

```
public ActionResult BudgetReporting(BudgetReportingViewModel model)
        {
            Common.GetDbExecutor().QueryNonQuery(Sql.InsertDocUnderReview, new {
                model.DocBudgetId, 
                DocNumber = model.DocUnderReview, // D is uppercase
                ReviewBy = Common.GetUserName(),
                ReviewComment = model.ReviewComment,
            }, 30).ToString();

            PopulateBudgetReportingDetail(model);

            return View(model);
        }

        public ActionResult GetDocUnderReviewDetails(Guid docBudgetId) // camelCase // 
        {
            var data = Common.GetKKDbExecutor().Query<BudgetReportingViewModel.ReviewRow>(Sql.GetDocUnderReviewDetails, new {
               docBudgetId
            }).ToList();

            return Json(data);
        }
```

#### Sql file

```
namespace BB360
{
    public partial class Sql
    {
        public const string GetDocUnderReviewDetails = @"

        select 
            DocBudgetId, 
            DocNumber, 
            ReviewBy, 
            convert(varchar, ReviewOn, 101) as ReviewOn, 
            isnull(ReviewComment, '') as ReviewComment 
            from DocBudgetReview 
            where DocBudgetId = @DocBudgetId
            order by ReviewOn desc   
        ";
    }
}
```

Comment: not sure it's relevant, but why are you sending a docNumber and docBudgetId since the server-side only takes a docBudgetId

Comment: In your Controller Method, You are accepting Guid Parameter and you are passing data as a string, so make Guid to String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I did some tinkering and got the table data to show.

In the stored procedure (`GetDocUnderReviewDetails.cs`) I commented out the line `where DocBudgetId = @DocBudgetId` and added `where DocNumber = @DocNumber`. I noticed that if I just commented out `where DBI =` then it showed *all* of the comments made for every modal, which was an issue I was dealing with earlier.

So now, my stored procedure looks like this:

```
namespace BB360
{
    public partial class Sql
    {
        public const string GetDocUnderReviewDetails = @"

        select 
            DocBudgetId, 
            DocNumber, 
            ReviewBy, 
            convert(varchar, ReviewOn, 101) as ReviewOn, 
            isnull(ReviewComment, '') as ReviewComment 
            from DocBudgetReview 
            --where DocBudgetId = @DocBudgetId
            where DocNumber = @DocNumber
            order by ReviewOn desc   
        ";
    }
}
```

I also added `string docNumber` to the Controller:

```
public ActionResult GetDocUnderReviewDetails(Guid docBudgetId, string docNumber)
        {
            var data = Common.GetBBDbExecutor().Query<BudgetReportingViewModel.ReviewRow>(Sql.GetDocUnderReviewDetails, new {
                docBudgetId,
                docNumber
            }).ToList();


            return Json(data);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is your "GetDocUnderReviewDetails" action accepts GET request and you're sending a post request to it. You just need to change the ajax request type to GET.

```
type: "GET",
url: "/Doc/GetDocUnderReviewDetails",
```

Another thing i noticed is that, you're sending the docNumber also in the request which your action doesn't require. Even though that won't cause any issue but you don't need to send that in ajax

Comment: Hi @manvinder-singh. It's definitely a POST request (even though there's `Get` in the url name) and the DocNumber appears at the top of the modal so it can be easily identified. The DocNumber's correctly appearing there.